# How can I flatten top document and sub document using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working on a mongoDB query.

Lets suppose I'm working on school data like following, where each level has a unique identifier. For the sake of this example lets suppose we have a list of last names attending each classroom:

```
School1
    Division1
        Classroom1
            Student1 last name
            Student2 last name
        Classroom2
            Student3 last name
            Student4 last name
    Divison2
        Classroom1
            -
        Classroom2
            -
School2
    -
        -
        -
    -
    -
```

I now want to write one query with which I get all the "flattened" info on all students in this format:

```
{
    School1,
    Division1,
    Classroom1,
    Student1 last name,
},
{
    School1,
    Division1,
    Classroom1,
    Student2 last name,
},
{
    School1,
    Division1,
    Classroom2,
    Student3 last name,
},
......
```

This is what I have so far:

```
db.students.aggregate(
[
    {
        $project: {
        school: "$school._id",
        division: "$school.division._id", 
        classroom: "$school.division.classroom._id",
        student: "$school.division.classroom.student._id",
        }
    },
        {$unwind:"$school"},
        {$unwind:"$division"},
        {$unwind:"$classroom"},
        {$unwind:"$student"},
]
)
```

With this I get the info I need but not in the desired format:

```
school: school1,
division: { division1},
classroom: {classroom1, classroom2},
student: {student1, student2, student3, student4}
```

What would be a good approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do projection after `$unwind`:

```
db.students.aggregate(
[
    {$match: {}},
    {$unwind:"$school"},
    {$unwind:"$division"},
    {$unwind:"$classroom"},
    {$unwind:"$student"},
    {
        $project: {
            school: "$school._id",
            division: "$division._id", 
            classroom: "$classroom._id",
            student: "$student._id",
        }
    },
]
)
```

Comment: Could you share your schema? I need to know which fields need unwind

Comment: would this also work if I have one student in more than one classroom? In that case I would need two appearances of that student.

Comment: Base on your schema above, i answer "yes". If your schema is different, you might modify the query